# If $Ax = b$ has a solution, does that mean the left null space of A is 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-equations

[image]

This is my approach:

For a solution to exist, $b$ has to be in column space. $b$ is an $m \times 1$ vector (as necessitated by the rules of matrix multiplication). This means it is a vector in $R^m$, so, for $b$ to be in column space, column space must also be $m$-dimensional. i.e. $r = m$, and $m - r$ (dimension of left null space) $= 0$?

However, I feel like I might be missing something in my understanding, and any clarity on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say "for every $b\in\Bbb R^m$" in your question, but, yes. Just as the nullspace of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the row space of $A$, the left nullspace of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the column space. For *every* $b$ to be in the column space is to say that the column space is all of $\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please clarify what you mean by your first line, about EVERY b in m-space? In my question, I'm referring to a given matrix A and a given vector b, for which we're trying to solve Ax = b, so as far as I can see, only that b needs to be in the column space for a solution to exist?

Comment: If you only know it for a single $b$, then you know only that the left nullspace is orthogonal to that single $b$. This is a highly crucial point. I might say that this is why one must  use language very carefully in mathematics.

Comment: So if we only know that a single b (e.g. one given in a question involving solving Ax = b) is in the column space of A, then the left null space of A is not necessarily 0? If so, what is wrong with the reasoning I outlined in my question? Why doesn't it apply for a single b which is in the column space of A?

Comment: Your error is far more serious than I realized. You are thinking that any subspace of $\Bbb R^m$ has dimension $m$ because all its vectors live in $\Bbb R^m$. You need to review what dimension of a subspace means. If the column space consists only of scalar multiples of a single (nonzero) vector, then the column space is $1$-dimensional, far from being $m$-dimensional.

Comment: I see. I've chewed on this a while, and I think I've identified the issue. The dimension of a subspace is the number of vectors that form its basis. So say we have A a 3x3 matrix, and b then a 3x1 vector. If A has a rank, say 2, then its column space is a two-dimensional plane (two 3x1 basis vectors) through the origin, and this plane itself lies in R3. So our 3x1 vector b, which is in R3, could still lie in this plane (this is geometrically obvious) to give a solution to Ax = b, and what I've said about r = m above, and m - r = 0 is incorrect, because here r = 2, m - r = 1.

Comment: Is this what you were getting at?

Comment: Yes. But if you know $Ax=b$ is consistent for every $b$, then the rank is $m$.

Comment: Perfect that makes sense now. Thanks for helping me clear up that misconception.